# Efficient way to bypass Error C2248 "cannot access protected member declared in class"

Tags: c++, protected, derived-class, poco-libraries

I'm implementing a c++ app and among others I also use Poco libraries. Specifically I 'm trying to use the poco logging framework. I have created a class that uses the following code from one of poco examples in order to create a logging mechanism:

```
 AutoPtr<PatternFormatter> pPatternFormatter(new PatternFormatter());
 AutoPtr<FormattingChannel>pFormattingChannel(new 
 FormattingChannel(pPatternFormatter));

 pPatternFormatter->setProperty("pattern", "%s: %p : %t");

 AutoPtr<ConsoleChannel> pConsoleChannel(new ConsoleChannel());
 pFormattingChannel->setChannel(pConsoleChannel);
```

However when I tried to replace the poco AutoPtr with poco SharedPtr pointer
I get the following build error:

**Error C2248   'Poco::FileChannel::~FileChannel': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Poco::FileChannel'**

I have searched and found that the FileChannel class has its destructor protected which I assume is used in order to prevent the deletion of the object via a pointer to its base.
Is it efficient to make my class derived from FileChannel with public or protected access specifier for the SharedPtr to work or it there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I thought about: What if the derived class makes the destructor simply public? Actually, it sounds too easy but I believe it should work.

Sample `test-prot-dtor.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {

  public:
    Base() { std::cout << "Base::Base()" << std::endl; }
  protected:
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Base::~Base()" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived: public Base {

  public:
    Derived() { std::cout << "Derived::Derived()" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived::~Derived()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
#if 0 // Does not work!
  Base *pBase = new Derived;
  delete pBase;
  /* here:
   * error: 'virtual Base::~Base()' is protected
   */
#endif // 0
  Derived *pDerived = new Derived;
  delete pDerived;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Tested with VisualStudio 2013 (Express) and gcc in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit). Below a sample session with the latter:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -c test-prot-dtor.cc

$ ./test-prot-dtor     
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()

$
```

About your idea (making `SharedPtr` a friend of your derived class) I'm not sure. It depends on implementation details of `SharedPtr` i.e. whether it "does the work itself" or delegates it to another (eventually even hidden) class/method or function...